# How to convert .dmp file into .hprof?

Tags: java, azure, heap-memory

I am trying to evaluate my application heap dump(.dmp) which is generated from the azure web app, there are no java tools supported to analyse the dump kindly help me the tools? or how to convert into .hprof

Comment: _unalize_ Do you mean **analyze** ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are similar to `.dump`, `.dmp` files are lightweight files that give quick information compared to `.hprof` files. By quick, I mean, point-in-time memory information compared to the detailed analysis that you could do using the latter.

So you wouldn't be able to convert one into another since they are used differently.

[image]